# convert second element of RDD tuple to array

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have following RDD:

```
res38: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[(String, Iterable[String])] = ShuffledRDD[5] at groupBy at <console>:14
```

now I want to get the second element of that tuple and put them in an array:

so I tried following:

```
scala> val items = data.map(x => x._2.toArray)
items: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[Array[String]] = MappedRDD[17] at map at <console>:16
```

and then to print the items: 
`items.take(4).foreach(printl`n)

but what I got is following:

```
[Ljava.lang.String;@223c67dc
[Ljava.lang.String;@2bc6ae13
[Ljava.lang.String;@ce77d9
[Ljava.lang.String;@731e47f8
```

I was expecting strings. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try converting the arrays to `String` before printing them. Something like:

```
items.take(4).foreach(x => println(x.mkString(" ")))
```